# When running my graph application for too long, there is sometimes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Anyone know why?

Tags: c#, collections

As part of a project, I created a program that collects external data at specific intervals (most often 1/second), and plot a graph out of it. Several times, while leaving the program running overnight as a stress test, the program sometimes encounter an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Here is part of the exception output:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
Parameter: index
    at
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
argument, ExceptionResource resource)
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
    at Macro_GUI.Macro_GUI.ChartReload_Part2()
    at Macro_GUI.Macro_GUI.ChartReload()
    at Macro_GUI.Macro_GUI.ScreenDataUpdate()
    at Macro_GUI.Macro_GUI.ScreenTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

ChartReload_Part2() is part of the continous re-drawing of the graph. This time the error happened after a collection time somewhat longer than 17 hours.

Reading about ArgumentOutOfRangeException, it seems to most often have something to do with the Capacity of a List Collection (there are several uses of a List in the method). Anyone know if I am on the right track or if the problem is something else? Or have I given to little information for anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

When you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=netframework-4.8):

**Exceptions**

ArgumentOutOfRangeException

*index is less than 0.*

*-or-*

*index is equal to or greater than Count.*

**Two possibilities:**

- either you are really out of bounds
- either you crossed `Int32.MaxValue` and therefore next value becomes negative

As you're letting it run overnight, it's highly possible you have so many items that you're encountering the second possiblity.

**Considerations:**

- a graph on a screen can't be `Int32.MaxValue` unless it's scrollable
- persist the data somehow on storage, summarize it, read it on the fly,

  - i.e. a list with billions of items should sound like a red flag to you
- check for alternative libraries, there might be some that already do that hard work for you

  - e.g. [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/) (untested)